# Path parameter passing issue in readme.io

Tags: swagger

In [readme.io](http://readme.io), when I pass my path parameters in the base URL of the API, they are not reflected in the backend and the response generates an error. What syntax or another mistake I might be making?

[image: path parameter passing screen]